# SharePoint 2010 Multiple Documents Uploads with Metadata Issue

Tags: sharepoint

I have recently encountered an issue with SharePoint 2010 when
uploading multiple documents. That is, if you have added additional
columns that are required, SharePoint does not prompt you to complete
the information, it just uploads the files. You then have to go back to
the library in datasheet view and manually complete the required
information for each document.

I'm looking for a way that makes SharePoint prompt you for the required
information before documents are uploaded. Is there any add-on software
or programming that could be done to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some 3rd party tools available(and some free stuff as well). Take a look at this, if it helps.

1. http://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint/bulk-file-upload-web-part
2. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11301.sharepoint-2010-bulk-metadata-tagging.aspx